# Send JSON from Android device to server not working

Tags: android, json

I have two links :

```
private static final String url_to_reg_device1 = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connec/regdevice.php";
private static final String url_to_reg_device2 = "http://www.something.in/form/regdevice.php";
```

One is for localhost and another is for server.

When I start activity, I create one JSON which store email and reg number and send it to server. On the server side, I decode JSON record and get values, store it in db.

The problem is that my code is working on local server. But when I upload it on server (to the URL in `url_to_reg_device2`), I got this error:

> "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".

Comment: the response of your second url must to be return a json... not a html.... i think a rewrite rule will be add your doctype..

Comment: @Rohit13 post some code.

Comment: I am not sure,But first off all try to convert the JSON into JSONStringer and pass to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check tags of JSON Object properly.

Comment: what do you mean? sorry but i don't understand.